# How to display different view everytime when a tabbar item is clicked in UITabBarBased app?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want screen 1 to be shown when tabbaritem 1 is clicked and if I change some settings, i go to different view, , when I click the tabbaritem 1 again I want to show screen 2.

I have a UITabbar based app and the MainWindow.xib has different tabs loaded before with views.

How do I change it programmatically?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

just put the code for the views to be created in the method `viewWillAppear` instead of `viewDidLoad`. This is being called each time go go back to your tab 1

Answer (score 0):

Turn `MainWindow` or `AppDelegate` into `UITabBarDelegate`, than use
`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`
to caught tab selections. When tab you need is selected, use `image` property of `UITabBarItem` to set image you like.

Answer (score 0):

Implement below method in your App Delegate

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers {

    UINavigationController *nc;
    nc = viewController;

    if(controller.selectedIndex == 3){
        [[nc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] replaceSubView];
    }
}
```

Here, 
if(controller.selectedIndex == 3)

3 = your viewcontroller index in which you want to change subview.

And "replaceSubView"

is your method in view controller in which you want to change subview.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Cheers.

Comment: everytime im adding a new subview while changing tabs..that is disturbing the images height and tabbar is hidden...please help

Comment: I am not getting you properly. You tabbar is hidden, then how will you click on it?